# Flatting an object into relative string

Tags: node.js, recursion

I have an object for example:

```
{
    test: {
        a1: {
            b1: "someText"
        },
        a2:2,
    },
    test2:{  
        a3:3,
        a4:{
            "b4": "otherText",
            "b5": "textText"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to iterate each possible key in the object and create a new object, where the key is a relative path, separated with underscores, to the original key and his value.

For example:

```
{ 
  test_a1_b1: 'someText',
  test_a2: 2,
  test2_a3: 3,
  test2_a4_b4: 'otherText',
  test2_a4_b5: 'texttext' 
}
```

Tried some recursive code but couldn't nail it. Will be happy to get your help with that!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so people can help you with it.

Comment: Yea, it sounds like someone wants help with his/her homework

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you posted is not [JSON](https://json.org/), those are [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Object_literal_notation_vs_JSON).

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice use case for the List monad, aka [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (stage 3)

Below `deepEntries` works similarly to `Object.entries`; it returns an array of `[ key, value ]` pairs.

```
const deepEntries = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ? Object.entries (o)
        .flatMap
          (([ k, v ]) => deepEntries (v, [ ...path, k ]))
    : [ [ path, o ] ]

console.log (deepEntries (data))
// [ [ [ 'test', 'a1', 'b1' ], 'someText' ]
// , [ [ 'test', 'a2' ], 2 ]
// , [ [ 'test2', 'a3' ], 3 ]
// , [ [ 'test2', 'a4', 'b4' ], 'otherText' ]
// , [ [ 'test2', 'a4', 'b5' ], 'textText' ]
// ]
```

This result is better than the proposed result in your question. If for some reason you need this lesser form, you can derive it easily

```js
deepEntries (data) .reduce
  ( (acc, [ keys, value ]) =>
      ({ ...acc, [keys .join ('_')]: value })
  , {}
  )
// { test_a1_b1: 'someText'
// , test_a2: 2
// , test2_a3: 3
// , test2_a4_b4: 'otherText'
// , test2_a4_b5: 'textText'
// }
```

If you need `flatMap` in your environment, you can easily polyfill it

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f)
{ return this .reduce
    ( (acc, x) =>
        acc .concat (f (x))
    , []
    )
}
```

Run the program below in your browser to verify the results

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f)
{ return this .reduce
    ( (acc, x) =>
        acc .concat (f (x))
    , []
    )
}

const deepEntries = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ? Object.entries (o)
        .flatMap
          (([ k, v ]) => deepEntries (v, [ ...path, k ]))
    : [ [ path, o ] ]

const data =
  { test:
      { a1: { b1: "someText" }
      , a2: 2
      }
  , test2 :
    { a3: 3
    , a4:
        { b4: "otherText"
        , b5: "textText"
        }
    }
  }

console.log (deepEntries (data))
// [ [ [ 'test', 'a1', 'b1' ], 'someText' ]
// , [ [ 'test', 'a2' ], 2 ]
// , [ [ 'test2', 'a3' ], 3 ]
// , [ [ 'test2', 'a4', 'b4' ], 'otherText' ]
// , [ [ 'test2', 'a4', 'b5' ], 'textText' ]
// ]

const lesserResult = 
  deepEntries (data) .reduce
    ( (acc, [ keys, value ]) =>
        ({ ...acc, [keys .join ('_')]: value })
    , {}
    )
console.log (lesserResult)
// { test_a1_b1: 'someText'
// , test_a2: 2
// , test2_a3: 3
// , test2_a4_b4: 'otherText'
// , test2_a4_b5: 'textText'
// }
```